# Query a Table of Invoices and Only Pull Complete Invoice Results

Tags: sql, mysql

I have three tables: `Invoice`, `Item`, and `Invoice_has_Item`. Each time I pull the new Invoices to be entered into these tables, it will add new Items that do not already exist, and these Items need to be manually gone through to correctly categorize into the right department. In the meantime, I'm looking to make a query of all Invoices who are not entered (invoice_entered = NULL), and who's all Items have been categorized into a department (Item.department_name != NULL).

This query pulls all Invoices that aren't entered, and then all of the Items that have departments, which results in me having incomplete Invoices to enter into the next system, leaving out all of the Items that do not have a department. Is there a way to query my Invoices to skip over Invoices that contain any Items with a NULL department? Hopefully this makes sense.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Invoice
INNER JOIN Invoice_has_Item ON Invoice.invoice_number = Invoice_has_Item.invoice_number
INNER JOIN Item ON Item.item_num = Invoice_has_Item.item_num
WHERE Item.account_num IS NOT NULL
    AND Invoice.invoice_entered IS NULL;
```

Comment: you should try LEFT JOIN instead

Comment: You might want to clarify your question by providing a few rows of sample data from all 3 tables, and the corresponding desired results. Please provide your data as tabular text (not as images).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to this solve this using WHERE NOT EXISTS as described by an answer previously posted here, combined with the LEFT JOIN recommended nbk. The query that resulted is as following:

```
SELECT * FROM Invoice
LEFT JOIN
    Invoice_has_Item ON Invoice.invoice_number = Invoice_has_Item.invoice_number
INNER JOIN
    Item ON Item.item_num = Invoice_has_Item.item_num
WHERE invoice_entered IS NULL
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM Invoice_has_Item
  INNER JOIN Item ON Item.item_num = Invoice_has_Item.item_num
  WHERE Invoice_has_Item.invoice_number = Invoice.invoice_number
  AND Item.account_num IS NULL
);
```